# I see a list of objects like a text in view [Rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, object, layout, text

I am facing a strange thing:
I am calling last 3 adverts from my model and try to put them in my view:

```
@last_adverts = Advert.last(3)


<%= @last_adverts.each do |advert| %>
    <%= render 'layouts/right_advert_template', :advert => advert %>
<% end %>
```

After rendering my template 3 times, below in the same view I see the list of these 3 objects as a text:

```
[#<Advert id: 21, title: "There is a title", text: "there is some text", author_name: "Kostya", created_at: "2015-09-17 18:19:32", updated_at: "2015-09-17 18:19:32", price: nil>, #<Advert id: 22, title: "qerqer", text: "reqwwer", author_name: "qwer", created_at: "2015-09-17 18:24:06", updated_at: "2015-09-17 18:24:06", price: nil>, #<Advert id: 23, title: "qwer", text: "erqwer", author_name: "qwerqq", created_at: "2015-09-17 18:27:13", updated_at: "2015-09-17 18:27:13", price: 123>]
```

Does anybody know how to hide this text?

Comment: no, I just make there @last_adverts.each block and get every advert title and a text.

Comment: <div class="rigtadvert">
 <div class="image">
  <a href="#"><img src="http://placehold.it/220x220&text=book cover" class="thumbnail"></a>
 </div>

 <div class="content">
  <h4><%= link_to "#{advert.title}", advert_path(advert) %></h5>
  <p>Здесь немного текста</p>
 </div>
 <div class="price">
  <h3>2000 руб</h3>
 </div>
 <hr>
</div>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should be

```
<%= @last_adverts.each do |advert| %>
    <%= render 'layouts/right_advert_template', :advert => advert %>
<% end %>
```

like this

```
<% @last_adverts.each do |advert| %>
    <%= render 'layouts/right_advert_template', :advert => advert %>
<% end %>
```

Notice the change in this line `<%= @last_adverts.each do |advert| %>`

`<% %>` - Executes the statement

`<%= %>` - Prints the output